# Side Scroller in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I've recently been interested in adventure side scroller games. I've never made one before but I have enough coding experience that I should be able to pick it up and make one. I've always thought they were cool and kind of reminded me of Pokemon which was my favorite game growing up. Here's what I need to know.

1. How do people determine specific properties for different tiles.
2. What's the most efficient way to code an adventure game
3. How do you add side scrolling functionality.
4. How do I incorporate a story into the game.

Now I understand what I'm asking is a lot so I'm not gonna ask you to explain how the universe works on a forum. I'd rather have you maybe point me in the right direction to a tutorial preferably made in python and pygame explaining how to create the basics of an adventure side scroller game. I have a lot of trouble understanding code if I don't start it from the beginning. Most sources I've found don't go into the depth I need to fully grasp the concept.

Any help is appreciated. If you want to answer maybe one of the questions very clearly that would help too. If you wanna answer them all be my guest but I'm really just looking for someone to point me in the right direction because I can't find any good tutorials on what I'm trying to learn.

Comment: I'm looking for a resource more broad than that and something that starts from scratch rather than some code examples of someone's broken code that I can barely understand. You see I've have not been doing this for an extremely long time so reading code isn't as easy for me as it is for others

Comment: I'm sorry, but stack overflow is not the place to ask for off-site resources.  But, here are some things that might be helpful: http://programarcadegames.com/ http://qq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tiles.html

Comment: Oh sorry I wasn't aware of that. As you could probably tell I'm new here. That's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Why do you want to use Python for this? I would recommend Unity and C#.